# Render view contain django location field in template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, postgis, geodjango

I writing an app that permits users to add and edit pump station with his location in map.
I have downloaded and installed caioariede/django-location-field

the problem is that when i render the view without location field all work perfect but when i add it, i get `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception error.

that is my template add_station.html:

```
{% extends "backend/main/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load forms_tags %}


{% block title %}{{meta_keyword}}{% endblock %}
{% block meta_keywords %}{{meta_keyword}}{% endblock meta_keywords %}
{% block meta_description %}{{meta_description}}{% endblock meta_description %}

{% block dash_title %}
    <i class="ppsmsite  ppsmsite-station-service"></i> {% trans "Station" %}
{% endblock %}

{% block dash_main %}
    {% include "backend/main/snippets/required_fields_infos.html" %}
    {% include "backend/main/snippets/alerts_messages.html" %}

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">{% trans "Enregistrer une nouvelle station" %}</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            {% form_div_row form.nom_station %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            {% form_div_row form.telephone %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <div class="col-lg-12">
                             {% form_div_row form.location %}
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            {% form_div_row form.city %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            {% form_div_row form.photo_station %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> {% trans "Enregistrer" %}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block add_scripts %}
    {{form.media}}
{% endblock add_scripts %}
```

My model:

```
class Station(models.Model):
    """Station service."""

    OPEN = 1
    CLOSE = 0
    STATUTLIST = (
       (OPEN, _("Ouverte")),
       (CLOSE, _("Fermée")),
    )
    nom_station = models.CharField(
      _('Nom de la station'), max_length=30)
    statut_station = models.CharField(
       _('Ouverte ou fermée'),
    max_length=1,
    choices=STATUTLIST, default=OPEN)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, verbose_name=_('Ville'))
    location = PlainLocationField(
    based_fields=['city'], zoom=7)
    photo_station = models.ImageField(
       _("Photo"),
       upload_to=utils.photo_file_path,
       storage=utils.photo_storage,
       null=True,
       blank=True,
       )
    telephone = PhoneNumberField(_('Numero de téléphone'), null=True)
```

my Form:

```
class StationForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""Docstring for StationsForm."""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Form Init."""
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(StationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields:
        if self.fields[field] is not None:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

class Meta:
    """Docstring for StationForm meta."""

    model = sitemodels.Station
    fields = [
        'telephone',
        'photo_station', 'location', 'city', 'nom_station']
```

my View:

```
def add_station_view(request, station_id=None):
"""Ajout et modification d'une station."""
template_name = "backend/main/add_station.html"
args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))

args['meta_keyword'] = args['home_title'] = _('Station')
args['meta_description'] = _('Création d\'une nouvelle station.')

if station_id is not None:
    args['cobject'] = get_object_or_404(
        sitemodels.Station, id=station_id)
    args['meta_description'] = _(
        'Editer %s' % (args['cobject'].get_nom_station()))
    form = siteforms.StationForm(
        request=request,
        instance=args['cobject']
    )

if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'cobject' in args and form.has_changed():
        form = siteforms.StationForm(
            request.POST,
            request=request,
            instance=args['cobject'])
        args['updated'] = True
    else:
        new_station = sitemodels.Station()
        form = siteforms.StationForm(
            request.POST,
            request=request,
            instance=new_station)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.save()
        if 'updated' in args:
            messages.success(request, STDUMSG)
        else:
            obj.cree_parking()
            obj.cree_catalogue()
            messages.success(
                request, _('Nouvelle station ajoutée'))
        if 'save_and_add_another' in request.POST:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse(
                    'ppsmsite:addstation',
                    current_app=request.resolver_match.namespace,
                )
            )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse(
                'ppsmsite:liststatio',
                current_app=request.resolver_match.namespace,
            )
        )
else:
    if 'cobject' not in args:
        form = siteforms.StationForm(request=request)
args['form'] = form
return render_to_response(
    template_name,
    args,
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

That's error i get when i try to render view:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /station/ajouter/

backend/main/add_station.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/station/ajouter/
Django Version:     1.8.7
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

backend/main/add_station.html

Exception Location:     C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in render_to_string, line 137
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version:     3.4.4
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\CRESUS\\Documents\\projet\\ppsm',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django_datetime_widget-0.9.3-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    jeu, 7 Avr 2016 02:56:52 +0100
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

    Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
        C:\Users\CRESUS\Documents\projet\ppsm\templates\backend\main\add_station.html (File exists)
    Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suit\templates\backend\main\add_station.html (File does not exist)
        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\backend\main\add_station.html (File does not exist)
        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\backend\main\add_station.html (File does not exist)
        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\templates\backend\main\add_station.html (File does not exist)
        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ckeditor\templates\backend\main\add_station.html (File does not exist)
        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ckeditor_uploader\templates\backend\main\add_station.html (File does not exist)
        C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\geoposition\templates\backend\main\add_station.html (File does not exist)
```

Please i need a help !

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /station/ajouter/
    
    backend/main/add_station.html

It seems the issue is with your templates. Check if your app directory has this `templates/backend/main/add_station.html`. If this fails, try removing only location field and then try again. If that works, then the rendering of location field needs to handled.

Comment: thx! location field needs to handled, but i don't know how to do !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to use third party libraries when geodjango has everything that you need and it's so easy to use?

Your location field should ideally be a [PointField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.PointField) Begin with.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Station(models.Model):

    ...
    ...
    location = PointField()
    ...
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Now you  have access to the vase geodjango api and allows you to perform queries to find out what pump stations are close to the user etc. Example:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance-lt

```
Station.objects.filter(poly__distance_lt=(point, D(m=5)))
```

Comment: thax allot my friends ! i'm new with geodjango the way is that i programm station pomp app from now i want to help site visitor to get road in map view to go in station like Need for speed game when you explore city !